# Check if child_process can run a command in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

how can I check if child_process can run a command?

'echo' is a valid command that can be run in a terminal, but 'echoes' is not one. For example, if I do this

```
const cp = require('child_process')
cp.exec('echo hello')
```

it will work.

If I do this, though

```
const cp = require('child_process')
cp.exec('echoes hello') //notice how it is echoes instead of echo
```

it will just error, but maybe the user has a program that adds 'echoes' to a terminal, and in that case, it would be able to run, but if it errors it will just exit out of the process and I won't be able to check if it works.

Is there any way to do this? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Do you have to check for invalid commands before running it, or can you just try the command, and if it fails you can tail it's invalid? (By the way, I don't know what your project is, but generally running people's command for what they just are usually isn't a good idea.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to manually loop through dirs in `$PATH` env & perform look up on those directory.
eg: `$PATH` is set to `/bin:/usr/local/bin` then you have to perform

```
fs.access('/bin/' + command, fs.constants.X_OK)
```

and

```
fs.access('/usr/local/bin/' + command, fs.constants.X_OK)
```

solution would look like this.

```js
const { constants: fsconsts } = require('fs')
const fs = require('fs/promises')
const path = require('path')
const paths = process.env.PATH.split(':')

async function isExecutable(command) {
  const cases = []
  for (const p of paths) {
    const bin = path.join(p, command)
    cases.push(fs.access(bin, fsconsts.X_OK)) // X_OK is bit flag which makes sure file is executable
  }
  await Promise.any(cases)
  return command
}

const found = (bin) => console.log('found', bin)

const notfound = (errors) => {
  console.log('not found or not executable')
  // console.error(errors)
}

// passes
isExecutable('echo').then(found).catch(notfound)
isExecutable('node').then(found).catch(notfound)

// fails
isExecutable('shhhhhh').then(found).catch(notfound)
isExecutable('echoes').then(found).catch(notfound)
```

NOTE: I think my solution works only on *nix based OSs

Comment: Thank you for this fast answer! Unfortunately, I am on a Mac and this doesn't run, but for anyone on a Windows computer, this should work! Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Grayseon you're kidding right ? I am on Linux, this works perfectly & should work on macos since it has $PATH env variable. not sure about windows.

Comment: It just says it can't find it 4 times. The error is "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'X_OK')" Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Ohh nevermind, found why it wasn't working. I changed `cases.push(fs.access(bin, fs.constants.X_OK))` to `cases.push(fs.access(bin))` and it worked. I'll make your answer the solution, edit if you want. Thank you, I would have never figured this out myself!

Comment: @Grayseon ah got it. in older version of node `fs/promises` didn't had `constants` props, it was done recently. Thats why you got error. Ill update my answer

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Sorry for the complications!